# SQLSTATE[23000] by adding a dummy test

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Both my tests hit a green state whenever I run them separately, but I hit SQLSTATE[23000] on first test whenever I run them together. The first test is a test I've previously made that makes sense to the application, the second is a dummy test as you can see.

I've resumed the error message because of the lot of classes from laravel that it shows, but it points to line 27 ('user_id' => 1).

**Test**

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\User;
use App\Tournament;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class TournamentTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic unit test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    use RefreshDatabase;

    protected function setUp() : void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        factory(User::class)->create();
        factory(Tournament::class)->create([
            'user_id' => 1
        ]);
    }

    /** @test **/
    public function index_page_shows_tournaments()
    {
        $user = User::first();

        $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('/tournaments');

        $response->assertViewIs('tournaments.index');
    }

    /** @test **/
    public function create_tournament_shows_number_of_challengers()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Unit\TournamentTest::create_tournament_shows_number_of_challengers
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`torneio`.`tournaments`, CONSTRAINT `tournaments_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `tournaments` (`user_id`, `name`, `interval`, `round`, `chal_num`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, Best Cross-group neutral support, 38, 1, 8, 1, 2019-05-09 00:56:44, 2019-05-09 00:56:44))

/home/tadeusvult/dev/torneio/tests/Unit/TournamentTest.php:27

Caused by
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`torneio`.`tournaments`, CONSTRAINT `tournaments_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the User being created doesn't end up with an ID of 1. What kind of database are you using for testing? Laravel resets the DB differently depending on the type, and it may not be resetting the User ID auto-increment.

Comment: I'm using mysql. I guess that's not the case because, as it works whenever there's one test, the setUp method seems to always be generating id 1 for the first user.

Answer (score 0):

The constraint violation error is telling there's no row with id=1 in `users` table. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1` would return empty.

[Laravel's document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) doesn't mention this behavior - [Rolling back a transaction will still increment the primary key](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7866). See also MySQL document: [“Lost” auto-increment values and sequence gaps](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html).

What is happening inside `setUp()` with `use RefreshDatabase;`:

```
protected function refreshTestDatabase()
{
    if (! RefreshDatabaseState::$migrated) {
        $this->artisan('migrate:fresh', ...);

        ...

        RefreshDatabaseState::$migrated = true;
    }
    $this->beginDatabaseTransaction();
}
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/RefreshDatabase.php#L52

When `TournamentTest` starts, auto_increment in `users` table will be reset by `migrate:fresh`, but it is not reset in each test case method. In other words, when `create_tournament_shows_number_of_challengers()` is running there's no row from `index_page_shows_tournaments()` because of rollback, but auto_increment still returns 2.

Try printing out the id in `setUp()`. It might be better not to use hardcoded number anyways:

```
protected function setUp() : void
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    var_dump($user->id); // see what's going on

    factory(Tournament::class)->create([
        'user_id' => $user->id // clearer intention
    ]);
}
```